# In my Unreal C++ class, how can I declare a UPROPERTY that will accept only instances of a specific Blueprint class?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

While it is well documented how `TSubclassOf<>` can be used to declare a property that will only accept instances of a known C++ class, I'm in the situation where I would like my C++ `AActor`-derived class to contain a property that will only accept references to instances of a specific Blueprint. (That Blueprint comes from a package that does not provide C++ header files.)

Comment: I've never done this sort of thing so this is kind of a long shot but I think you may want to write a [details customization](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/ProgrammingAndScripting/Slate/DetailsCustomization/) for the "`AActor`-derived class" using `SAssetProperty` and using `AllowedClass` with something like `ConstructorHelpers::ClassFinder` to get the UClass of the "specific Blueprint".

Comment: If you find an answer that works for you please consider [self-answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) below, I'm definitely interested in how this can be done.

Comment: @ruzihm My apologies. I don't think I should post a self-answer, since I do not have a direct answer. Indirectly though, the answer probably is: derive a Blueprint class from your C++ class, then handle inter-class communication in Blueprint. If it gets complicated, code the complex stuff in the C++ class, and use the results from Blueprint.

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting question so I wanted to provide one possible answer, which is a workaround with a minimal derived BP class and property reflection. I'm writing this without the engine available for compilation, so apologies if I've gotten anything wrong.

```
UCLASS(Blueprintable)
class AMyActor : public AActor
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
    // Name of the required blueprint class property, which must be added in a derived blueprint
    constexpr FName ClassPropertyName = TEXT("BlueprintClass")

protected:
    /* Get the value of the blueprint class property. */
    UClass* GetBlueprintClass();
};


UClass* AMyActor::GetBlueprintClass()
{
    FObjectProperty* BlueprintClassProperty = FindFProperty<FObjectProperty>(GetClass(), ClassPropertyName);
    checkf(BlueprintClassProperty != nullptr, TEXT("AMyActor must used via a derived BP type with a %s property."), *ClassPropertyName.ToString()))
    
    UObject* PropertyValue = BlueprintClassProperty->GetObjectPropertyValue_InContainer(this);
    if (PropertyValue != nullptr)
    {
        return CastChecked<UClass>(PropertyValue);
    }

    return nullptr;
}
```

You should be able to derive this in BP and add the required BlueprintClass property. There's no other logic required on the BP side, you just get the value of the property using the GetBlueprintClass method in C++. There's a little overhead there, so you may want to cache the value e.g. on actor construction or BeginPlay.